# How to disable Refreshing in SwipeRefreshLayout while Drag & Drop Event occurs from Top to Bottom in Recycler View Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, swiperefreshlayout

I had an Issue of swipe refresh layout, it starts refreshing while drag and drop event occurs from top to bottom. I can't disable while drag event occurs, thanks if any reply!

Comment: why are using `SwipeRefreshLayout` if you do not want the drag & drop gesture event?

Comment: yes I understood, but I need of Swipe Refresh Layout for Update list in Recyclerview and Drag & Drop for Swap items in Recyler view

Answer (score 2):

When the drag & drop event starts you could disable the SwipeRefresh with `setEnabled(false)` and enable it again after the d&d event stoped with `setEnabled(true)`